# query works in mysql terminal but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I build my query in PHP dynamically, and when I try to execute it, it fails. When I copy the query it generated and paste it into the mysql terminal and run it, it works fine. The error I get is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>' at line 1" for the following query:

```
UPDATE events SET event = 'orgo lecture', start = '2014-07-24 16:00:00' WHERE userID = 1 AND eventID = 5
```

The following is the code used to generate the query dynamically:

```
$query = "UPDATE events SET ";
$query_list = array();
if ($set_event) {

    $query_list[] = "event = '{$event}'";

}
if ($set_start) {

    $query_list[] = "start = '{$start}'";

}
if ($set_end) {

    $query_list[] = "end = '{$end}'";

}
$query_list_size = count($query_list);
for ($i = 0; $i < $query_list_size - 1; $i++) {

    $query .= $query_list[$i];
    $query .= ", ";

}
$query .= $query_list[$query_list_size - 1];
$query .= " WHERE userID = {$userID} AND eventID = {$eventID}";
echo $query .= "<br />";
$query_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: You're appending a line break to your query and then using that in your $query_result variable.

Comment: change `echo $query .= "<br />";` to `echo $query . "<br />";`

Comment: try this replacement line $query .= " WHERE userID = " . $userID . " AND eventID = " . $eventID . "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is this:

```
echo $query .= "<br />";
```

Should be

```
echo $query . "<br />";
```

Ironically, by checking your query you were breaking it.

As a side note,

```
$query_list_size = count($query_list);
for ($i = 0; $i < $query_list_size - 1; $i++) {

   $query .= $query_list[$i];
   $query .= ", ";

}
$query .= $query_list[$query_list_size - 1];
```

Could be shortened to:

```
 $query .= implode(", ", $query_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `echo $query .= "<br />";` instruction is changing the query and making it invalid SQL.  Why not use `echo $query . "<br />";`?